# Dynamic Post Thumbnail →

Tags: theme-development, post-thumbnails

I have an HTML code here →

```
<!-- Page Header -->
    <!-- Set your background image for this header on the line below. -->
    <header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('img/home-bg.jpg')">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="site-heading">
                        <h1> Clean Blog </h1>
                        <hr class="small">
                        <span class="subheading">A Clean Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

I was trying to convert this into WP dynamically.

How to convert this dynamically →

```
 <header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('img/home-bg.jpg')">
```

`style="background-image: url('img/home-bg.jpg')` → How to convert this dynamically so that the image in the background should come from wordpress features image section.

I was trying this, but it didn't worked =

```
<header class="intro-header" style="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [the_post_thumbnail_url()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url):

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>')">
```

Comment: Oh my I didn't even realize there was a function that did that -- my answer is more complicated than it needs to be!

Comment: Well, it did just appear as of [WP v4.4](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.4). It's hard to keep track of all the little goodies that crop up in each release! (Which is awesome!)

Comment: Done. Thank You. In 5 minutes I am posting one more doubt in another thread. please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The function `the_post_thumbnail` returns the entire HTML for the image. You will need to use [`wp_get_post_thumbnail_id`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) and [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) in combination to get the image's url.

Here's a helper function I usually throw into `functions.php` when I'm building a theme to make this easier:

```
function mytheme_get_image_url( $size = 'full' ) {
    $image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), $size );
    return $image_data[0];
}
```

Usage:

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('<?php echo mytheme_get_image_url(); ?>')">
```

Comment: I like your answer also, but I am unable to select both the answers.

Comment: @WordpressNovice My answer isn't really correct -- the only reason I didn't delete it was for the explanation of `the_post_thumbnail`. No worries!